# how to count all rows belonging to userid?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$userid = $_SESSION[userid]
$sqll = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM entries WHERE userid='$userid'");
```

Is using `count(id)` efficient? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`count(*)` should do.

Make sure you escape `$userid`, though.

**Edit**: just half-a-word of explanation. `count(column)` counts all rows for which `column` is not null. Using `*` is supposed to be the most efficient way of counting rows regardless of content and more descriptive in case someone (including yourself) is ever going to (re)read the code.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have an index on your userid column (if it's a primary key, you already do).

If you've got userid as a primary key, then this should be an efficient query and will have the same efficiency as using count(*).

Answer (score 1):

Some say it's more efficient to use `COUNT(*)`
it also depends how often are you going to count this value and how often is it going to change. May be it's better to cache it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need to count the id column specifically you can use `COUNT(*)`, which may be faster with some engines.

Comment: And better describes the intention.